# cmake and osx frameworks not found

Tags: c++, cmake, javascriptcore

I m making some experiments dealing with C++, Android JNIs and the JavaScriptCore framework provided by OSX platforms.

I'm having some troubles while using cmake to load the JavascriptCore framework. It seems that its not able to find it...

I'm having the following code in my cmakelist:

```
find_library(JSCORE JavaScriptCore)
if (NOT JSCORE)
    MESSAGE(ERROR ": Framework JSCore not found")
endif()
```

and I'm always passing in it.

I don't know why and I suspect a path problem.

Does anybody know or have some suggestion so that I can load the JSCore framework inside my C++ lib?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Configuring the following project allows to successfully find the library. Would you have a complete example to share ?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(Test)

find_library(JSCORE_LIBRARY JavaScriptCore)
if(NOT JSCORE_LIBRARY)
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Framework JSCore not found")
endif()
message(STATUS "JSCORE_LIBRARY: ${JSCORE_LIBRARY}")
```

Output:

```
$ /Volumes/Dashboards/Support/CMake-3.12.0.app/Contents/bin/cmake ../
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 8.0.0.8000042
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 8.0.0.8000042
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- [...]
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- JSCORE_LIBRARY: /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/test/bld
```

Comment: The build is working when I launch cmake locally. It seems to be a problem with my current config and Android Studio + NDK/JNI + compiling C++ program :o

Comment: What's weird here is that if I try to build the project using cmake manually, I'm having javascriptcore but not jni.h.. The inverse is also true while I'm trying to build the app using Android Studio, it doesn't find the javascriptcore.h interface